# MongoDB for small production project with very low traffic but with opportunity to scale fast

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, production, heroku-postgres

I've faced the problem with DBs (specifically with MongoDB).

At first, I thought to deploy it to `MongoDB Atlas Cloud` but the production Clusters (`M30` and higher) are quite expensive for a little project like mine.

Now I am thinking about deploying the `MongoDB` replica set somewhere on Heroku Dyno or maybe AWS instance.

Couldn't you please suggest any production-ready way/solution that would not cost much?

As I can see AWS offers some FREE Tiers for DBs (`Amazon RDS`, `Amazon DynamoDB`, and others) but is it really free or it's a trap? Because I heard `AWS` Pricing policy is not that honey-sweet as it looks on the pricing page (in reality)

Any advice or help is welcomed!

Comment: Does your small project still require full failover with a replica set?   If you can get away with a daily dump and a script to run mongoimport, then running `mongod` on a baby AWS instance is the least expensive way to go.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti No, I thought maybe there is a way to have full MongoDB support with mongoose ORM and at the same time have it less expensive. I am new to DB and backend so I thought there are some tricks to do. So far I can see a few options and I would like to hear your thoughts on them: 1) would it be less expensive or even possible to deploy MongoDB on one AWS or Heroku instance as a replica set (because I need the full MongoDB functionality - transitions, aggregation framework, and the operators like $where and others which are excluded from the shared clusters on Atlas)

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti the option 2) I've got an old personal server. It's in dust for years already but I already thought maybe it would be better to put it up and deploy my DBs on it. That's gonna take some time and I am not sure what kind of pitfalls has each of the options. I am sure If I keep everything on my server that's gonna be a headache to keep it up all the time and connected 24/7. Or maybe some other things. I am saying nothing about scaling. But in some sense I find this way nice - to have the full control of it and it must be less expensive with the full fuctionality

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I've noticed that many people nowadays use PostgresDB. Is it less expensive, don't you know? Because I saw AWS provides some options for it with 12 months free tier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your least expensive way to experiment with MongoDB that still offers a path to scaling to something much larger is to get a free tier EC2 instance like a `t2.micro` and install MongoDB Community on it yourself.  The Linux 64bit distribution is available here:  https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon-5.0.5.tgz.  Simply run `tar xf` on that tarfile and the `mongod` server and `mongo` CLI executables will be extracted.  No other config required and pretty much you would start it like this:

```
$ mkdir -p /path/to/dbfiles
$ mongod --dbpath /path/to/dbfiles --logpath /path/to/dbfiles/mongo.log --replSet "rs0" --fork
```

You do *not* need a replica set to use aggregation, transactions, etc.
This solution will also expose you to a lot of important things like network security, database security, log management, driver compatibility, key vaults, and using the AWS Console and perhaps the AWS CLI to manipulate the environment.  You can graduate to a bigger machine and create and add members to a replica set later -- or you can take the plunge and go with MongoDB Atlas.  But at that point you'll be comfortable with functions esp. the aggregation pipeline, the document model, drivers, etc., all learned on essentially a zero-cost platform.

Performance is not really an issue here but using the handy load generator POCDriver (https://github.com/johnlpage/POCDriver) on a `t2.micro` instance with no special setup and a doc size of 0.28Kb, with 90/10 read/insert mix on a default of 4 threads and batch update removed (-b 1), we get about 450 inserts/sec and 4200 reads/sec on primary key `_id`.

```
java -jar POCDriver.jar --host "mongodb://localhost:27017" -k 90 -i 10 -b 1
```

Of course, the load generator is competing with the DB engine itself for resources but as a first cut it is good to know the performance independent of network considerations.
From launching the EC2 instance to running the test including installing java `sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64` took about 5 mins.

Comment: How much traffic do you think this setup can handle? How many simultaneous operations I/O can it serve?

Comment: So far one of the benefits of using this setup is the full MongoDB functionality with zero expenses for 1 year, right? Because MongoDB Atlas has a lot of restrictions for Shared Clusters. Your setup I believe doesn't have them as you say you can use the whole pack: Transactions, Aggregations, operations like $where, and others.

Comment: @midnight_dev  Answer updated with results from POCDriver.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Thank you a lot for not leaving me alone with that mess as it seems so far for me. I'm gonna play around with that soon and I'm sure I'll have lots of other questions) if you don't mind I'll tag you there too